# Xcode UI tests with login system

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have an app with a login system, so once user have logged in the app, I store their session in a local DB, which prevents users to have log in every time they use the app. Obviously, if users have not logged in, the app displays a `LoginViewController`, but if the app detects a current session for the user, a `HomeViewController` is displayed.

I have created a few tests for my `HomeViewController` and they all work fine. However, I have realised they are working fine because the app currently has a session stored. If I enter the app and logout the current user, when I run the UI tests they will fail. This makes sense, as the test expects a `HomeViewController` to be displayed, and instead the `LoginViewController` is shown.

Considering that I would also like to create UI tests for the `LoginViewController`, it seems reasonable to create a solution where, in each test, I set if the user is logged in or not. How can I do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, found the answer at `XCUIApplication` launch arguments/environments. This allows you to send certain configuration when executing the test that can be interpreted by your main code later.

For my case to work, I placed the following code:

```
// UI Test
func testWelcomeIsShown() {
   let app = XCUIApplication()
   app.launchArguments.append("isUITestingLogin")
   app.launch()
   // Rest of your test steps
}

// AppDelegate or wherever you fetch your current session
func getCurrentSession() {
    if NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments.contains("isUITestingLogin") {
        session = nil
    } else {
        session = DatabaseManager.getSession()
    }
}
```

**Note:** This code will work for recording and executing your test. However, if you do have multiple tests with the same logic, you would probably move the first 3 lines of `testWelcomeIsShown()` to the `setUp()` of the test class. However, it is important to remember that this setup is not executed when recording the test, so you need to manually set a no current session environment.

Comment: freaking finally... thank you so much... this solved a problem that stole 4 hours of my life

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively use [SBTUITestTunnel](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel) which among other things allows you to upload a file from your test target to the app's sandbox. It should be enough to prepare a DB with prefilled login informations which then gets sent to the apps' target on startup.

The beauty of the library is that the app's code isn't polluted with test code.